# At what point does it become "Developer intent"?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/184955), and one of the first comments suggested that it was developer intent/required developer knowledge.

I could be persuaded either way, so at what point does this kind of question become "developer intent"?

Answer (score 6):

It would seem perfectly acceptable to me to ask **what the third slot is for**. It is a thing that is in the game and you are curious about it.

(Full disclosure; I am basing the following as someone who has not played Destiny, and is relying on your description of your question and the link in the question to provide context)

But it sounds like whatever goes in that third slot **is not yet implemented yet** - which means the only possible answer for the moment is "**we don't know**". *Anything further* would be speculation of developer intent, or speculation on unreleased content.

We can not know what goes into that slot until whatever it is has been implemented. Any plans the developers had or have for that slot could change between now and whenever *something* is released to the public.

---

Which brings us to the probable reason why your question could conceivably be considered off-topic as it stands: It takes *speculation* on the likely purpose of the slot, and then (partially) asks **how the speculated system would work**. If there is any doubt that this is what you are essentially asking, you yourself follow it up with "*Or even what it is actually for?*".

Comment: So basically, at this point: no it's not off-topic, but I shouldn't expect an answer any time soon?

Comment: I would strongly consider revising your question to focus more on the central question of "what is the third subclass slot for?", and placing less emphasis on the theory presented in the reddit thread. The focus on the reddit thread's theory is what has *me* on the fence about voting to close it.

Comment: You might get answers, but by the sound of it, like I said in the answer here, the only authoritative answer that can be given *currently* is "We don't know, it has not been implemented yet." followed (hopefully) by an update once whatever it is has been implemented and pushed to live (or public beta, if that's a thing that exists with Destiny).

Comment: The game has been released. I believe it has been out for about a month now

Comment: Yess... I do not believe I have called the release state of the game into question. What prompted that comment? My mention of "public beta"? Many online games have a beta version that runs at the same time as the live version, allowing people to preview upcoming changes and bug-test them before the patch is pushed onto the main servers.

Comment: Ah. Yes that confused me a little. You were referring to like what Minecraft does with it's snapshots. Forgive me

Comment: No need to ask forgiveness, we're all on the same page now; the confusion has been clarified.

Comment: `It is a thing that is in the game and you are curious about it.` That's it exactly. It's in the game and people don't know if it's just not implemented, or if they haven't unlocked something, or have a bug, or what. The answer "It does nothing at the moment" is a perfectly valid answer that may not be obvious to everyone. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @Sterno To argue the other side, `It is a thing that is in the game, and some people think it does this.  Does it do this random thing people think it might be for?` tends to have speculation at the root of the question.  If you limit the question itself to just, `This is a thing in game, what does it do?`, that sounds like a perfectly acceptable question.  Grounding your question in speculation by using random information found online, though, can be (and as you can see, was) problematic.